# Host single line message to local network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I can do `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000` to host the contents of the current directory to port `9000` on the local network.

However, is there a way to simply host a single-lined message?

e.g.:

```
some_prog -m "hello!" 9000
```

This doesn't need to be with Python, but preferably with a program that is installed by default on a Linux distribution (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with netcat.

`while true; do echo "mymessage" | nc -l -p 9000 -q1; done`

Read the nc man-page for full details.

Comment: Hmm, it would be faster for me to write a file first with a message and typing the python command than remembering this though. I'm looking for a command that is about as simple as the example I posted.

Comment: Put a small function in your .bashrc: `function serve {while true; do echo $1 | nc -l -p 9000 -q1; done}` Now you can start a webserver with `serve mymessage`.

Comment: I want this to be usable on a completely fresh ubuntu install, I want to avoid using aliases or functions.

Comment: All the commands I used are default tools on all GNU/Linux distributions I know. I'm not aware of any tool that would make serving a static message easier.